# Grouping Data TSQL

Tags: forms, t-sql, group-by, subquery

I'm trying to make a report which shows a users submitted forms.

I want each line to show one occurrence of each filed per user.

Username | First form submitted | Form address (1st form) | Last form submitted | Form Address (last form)

Here's what I have **currently**:

```
SELECT    form.Name
             ,(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM dbo.vAdvF_155 af WHERE af.Name = form.Name) AS [TotalForms]
             ,(SELECT TOP 1 p.Timetag1 FROM dbo.vAdvF_155 af WHERE af.Name = form.Name ORDER BY [TimeTag1] ASC) AS [Started]
             ,(SELECT TOP 1 af.aField143 FROM dbo.vAdvF_155 af WHERE af.TimeTag1 = form.TimeTag1 ORDER BY [TimeTag1] DESC) AS [FirstFormAddress]
             ,(SELECT TOP 1 p.Timetag2 FROM dbo.vAdvF_155 af WHERE af.Name = form.Name ORDER BY [TimeTag2] DESC) AS [Submitted]
             ,(SELECT TOP 1 af.aField143 FROM dbo.vAdvF_155 af WHERE af.RecId = form.RecId ORDER BY [TimeTag2] DESC) AS [LastFormAddress]

FROM         dbo.vAdvF_155 AS form INNER JOIN
             dbo.PhoneData AS p ON form.RecId = p.RecID
             ORDER BY form.Name
```

**Results:**

```
Name    TotalForms  Started FirstFormAddress    Submitted   LastFormAddress
CARL SUTTON 14  2016-07-22 09:30:55.000 19 Lilac Close KEYWORTH 2016-07-22 11:17:36.000 19 Lilac Close KEYWORTH
CARL SUTTON 14  2016-07-22 12:46:31.000 23 Lincoln Street NEWARK    2016-07-22 13:20:19.000 23 Lincoln Street NEWARK
CARL SUTTON 14  2016-07-25 10:24:52.000 104 Shireoaks COMMON    2016-07-25 12:04:59.000 104 Shireoaks COMMON
CARL SUTTON 14  2016-07-25 13:59:11.000 43 Milton DRIVE RAVENSHEAD  2016-07-25 15:53:28.000 43 Milton DRIVE RAVENSHEAD
CARL SUTTON 14  2016-07-26 10:22:53.000 17 LISMORE COURT MANSFIELD  2016-07-26 11:36:07.000 17 LISMORE COURT MANSFIELD
CARL SUTTON 14  2016-07-26 13:52:02.000 3 Ruby's AVENUE  BALDERTON  2016-07-26 15:51:42.000 3 Ruby's AVENUE  BALDERTON
CARL SUTTON 14  2016-07-27 09:35:54.000 The Elms Station Road NG14 7GD  2016-07-27 14:53:28.000 The Elms Station Road NG14 7GD
CARL SUTTON 14  2016-07-28 09:09:10.000 Main Road BULCOTE   2016-07-28 10:35:17.000 Main Road BULCOTE
CARL SUTTON 14  2016-07-28 12:04:17.000 NULL    2016-07-28 12:06:21.000 NULL
CARL SUTTON 14  2016-07-28 13:13:48.000 2 Midlands AVENUE STAPLEFORD    2016-07-28 15:14:32.000 2 Midlands AVENUE STAPLEFORD
CARL SUTTON 14  2016-07-31 08:14:03.000 Summit Close KIRKBY 2016-07-31 11:44:32.000 Summit Close KIRKBY
CARL SUTTON 14  2016-07-31 12:49:29.000 4 Archway Old Clipstone     2016-07-31 14:07:05.000 4 Archway Old Clipstone 
CARL SUTTON 14  2016-08-01 08:20:21.000 5 RAVENSHEAD COURT  2016-08-01 10:08:39.000 5 RAVENSHEAD COURT
CARL SUTTON 14  2016-08-02 07:56:23.000 Field CLOSE GEDLING 2016-08-02 09:48:13.000 Field CLOSE GEDLING
CASEY MORTON    13  2016-07-22 09:12:08.000 10 ByRON CRESENT Ng162sx    2016-07-22 11:42:30.000 10 ByRON CRESENT Ng162sx 
CASEY MORTON    13  2016-07-22 13:27:12.000 146     2016-07-22 16:05:29.000 146 
CASEY MORTON    13  2016-07-25 09:14:37.000 5 Cossall Road NG93PG   2016-07-25 14:16:53.000 5 Cossall Road NG93PG 
CASEY MORTON    13  2016-07-26 08:28:14.000 TenYSON Street NG74GA   2016-07-26 11:46:42.000 TenYSON Street NG74GA 
CASEY MORTON    13  2016-07-26 14:31:17.000 NULL    2016-07-26 14:54:23.000 NULL
CASEY MORTON    13  2016-07-27 06:38:28.000 34 Sturton STREET Ng76hu    2016-07-27 09:24:37.000 34 Sturton STREET Ng76hu 
CASEY MORTON    13  2016-07-27 09:59:05.000 12 TUDOR Close Ng42dr   2016-07-27 15:04:08.000 12 TUDOR Close Ng42dr 
CASEY MORTON    13  2016-07-28 08:43:23.000 12 Ardmore Ng24gp   2016-07-28 11:27:35.000 12 Ardmore Ng24gp 
CASEY MORTON    13  2016-07-28 11:48:28.000 9 Sycamore Close NG122DJ    2016-07-28 13:46:55.000 9 Sycamore Close NG122DJ
CASEY MORTON    13  2016-07-28 14:40:49.000 15 GoodLIFFE STREET Ng76fz  2016-07-28 15:54:07.000 15 GoodLIFFE STREET Ng76fz 
CASEY MORTON    13  2016-08-01 09:50:08.000 24 VALESIDE Gardens NG42EP  2016-08-01 12:28:27.000 24 VALESIDE Gardens NG42EP 
CASEY MORTON    13  2016-08-01 13:51:53.000 285 Derby Road Ng93ja   2016-08-01 16:09:11.000 285 Derby Road Ng93ja 
CASEY MORTON    13  2016-08-02 07:21:38.000 Melrose House Raleigh Street Ng74hf     2016-08-02 11:24:27.000 Melrose House Raleigh Street Ng74hf
```

As you can see with the results it shows all the forms as they are not distinct, I literally just want it grouped into one line per person but can't figure the grouping.

Comment: Can you provide the source table and a selection of the data within them?  Doing so many sub selects is generally a bad idea...
You have duplicates in your data because you haven't used a `GROUP BY` statement before your `ORDER BY` at all and it appears you need to apply some additional filtering on your `form` table, as it is pulling back all the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a lot about the structure of your vAdvF_155 table/view, you may be able to get the results you are looking for with this:

```
declare @vAdvF_155 table (Name nvarchar(50)
                            ,aField143 nvarchar(50)
                            ,Timetag1 datetime
                            ,Timetag2 datetime
                            )
insert into @vAdvF_155 values
('CARL SUTTON'  ,'4 Archway Old Clipstone'  ,'2016-07-31 12:49:29.000','2016-07-31 14:07:05.000')
,('CARL SUTTON' ,'5 RAVENSHEAD COURT'       ,'2016-08-01 08:20:21.000','2016-08-01 10:08:39.000')
,('CARL SUTTON' ,'Field CLOSE GEDLING'      ,'2016-08-02 07:56:23.000','2016-08-02 09:48:13.000')
,('CASEY MORTON','10 ByRON CRESENT Ng162sx' ,'2016-07-22 09:12:08.000','2016-07-22 11:42:30.000')
,('CASEY MORTON','146 Street Name'          ,'2016-07-22 13:27:12.000','2016-07-22 16:05:29.000')
,('CASEY MORTON','5 Cossall Road NG93PG'    ,'2016-07-25 09:14:37.000','2016-07-25 14:16:53.000')


select f.Name
        ,f.TotalForms
        ,f.FirstForm
        ,ff.aField143 as FirstFormAddress
        ,f.LastForm
        ,lf.aField143 as LastFormAddress
from (
    select Name
            ,count(1) as TotalForms
            ,min(Timetag1) as FirstForm
            ,max(Timetag2) as LastForm
    from @vAdvF_155
    group By Name
    ) f
    inner join @vAdvF_155 ff
        on(f.Name = ff.Name
            and f.FirstForm = ff.Timetag1
            )
    inner join @vAdvF_155 lf
        on(f.Name = ff.Name
            and f.LastForm = lf.Timetag2
            )
```

Comment: As you said I think I was complicating it too much with all the sub-queries.

I've broken the code up to look how it was all working (your answer) and this brings back the results as needed.

Many thanks for your help on this one!